# Will this firewall configuration prevent unencrypted traffic?

Tags: firewall, encryption, browser, https

All incoming and outgoing traffic denied.
Allowed outgoing ports: 53,67,68,443

Since I have not allowed port 80 and since programs use port 443 for https traffic by default, will this configuration block unencrypted traffic?

I know https does not have to use port 443 but that is what is used by default, right? Do all common programs like browsers use port 443 for https?

Except for DNS queries perhaps. Are those made in http? And if I am correct, some browsers now offer an option to do this over https. But other than that will everything else be encrypted?

Comment: Do you have a rule to accept RELATED and ESTABLISHED traffic (i.e. replies to your permitted outbound data)?

Comment: @roaima I don't think another rule is needed to get a reply.  By allowing connection to port 443 of a website I am saying that I want to accept a reply to a request that I send. I just want to know that if I don't allow connections to port 80, can I be sure all my traffic will be encrypted?

Comment: I am aware that some services or websites might not be available on https but that's what I want. If something is not available on https and needs http I want it to be blocked.

Comment: to be paranoid, when a browser (not all the browsers behave the same) is doing an HTTPS request with TLS client hello [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), as of today, the site hostname is in cleartext. So it's still possible to sniff what sites you are visiting. It was already possible with the DNS request made just before.